# display: flex - высота элементов

Tags: css, html5

Не могу понять почему не флексы не совпадают по высоте с большим элементом(флекс). Попробовал  `align-items: stretch` - не помогает. Высоту фиксированную задавать не хочу.

```
  *{
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    .product{
      max-width: 1200px;
      padding-left: 15px;
      padding-right: 15px;
      margin-left: auto;
      margin-right: auto;
      margin-bottom: 55px;
    }

    .title-product{
      font-size: 20px;
      font-weight: bold;
      line-height: 24px;
      text-transform: uppercase;
      text-align: center;
    }


    .title-product::after{
       content: " ";
      display: block;
      width: 64px;
      margin-top: 8px;
      margin-bottom: 23px;
      margin-left: auto;
      margin-right: auto;
      border: 2px solid #e1d9bd;
      background-color: #e1d9bd;
    }

    .img-product{
      display: flex;
      align-items: stretch;
      justify-content: space-between;
      
      }
    /* .img-products{
      position: relative;
    } */

    .picture-product{
      width: 300px;
      padding: 25px 25px 0 25px;
      }

    .products-body{
      width: 300px;
    /*   height: 270px; */
      border: 2px solid #b59f5b;
      padding: 55px 25px 25px 25px;
    /*   position: relative;
      top: -50px; */
    }

    .product-title{
      font-size: 19px;
      line-height: 24px;
      margin-bottom: 15px;
      text-transform: uppercase;
    }

    .product-body{
      margin-bottom: 25px;
    }

    .product-text{
     font-size: 14px;
      font-weight: 400;
      line-height: 22px;
      color: #0f0d0e; 
    }

    .text{
      color: #b59f5b;
      text-decoration: none;
    }

    .product-footer{
      display: flex;
      justify-content: space-between;
      align-items: flex-end;
    }

    .product-prices{
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
    }
    .product-price-olds{
      text-decoration: line-through;
      font-size: 11px;
      font-weight: 600;
    }

    .product-rub{
      font-size: 14px;
      font-weight: 600; 
    }

    .product-price{
      font-size: 17px;
      font-weight: 600;
    }

    .product-button{
      width: 137px;
      height: 46px;
      border: none;
      background-color: #b59f5b;
      text-transform: uppercase;
      text-decoration: none;
      color: white;
      font-size: 14px;
      text-align: center;
    }
```

```html
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>

    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
      <title>replit</title>
      <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    </head>

    <body>
      <article class="product">
          <h2 class="title-product">наши изделия</h2>
            <div class="img-product">
              <div class="img-products">
              <img class="picture-product" src="image/shop-item-desk1.jpg" alt="сад на подоконнике">
                <div class="products-body">
                <div class="product-body">
                  <div class="product-content">
                    <h3 class="product-title">подушки на диван</h3>
                    <p class="product-text">Набор из двух подушек с модными принтами. видео о создании <a class="text" href="#">здесь</a>.</p>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="product-footer">
                  <div class="product-prices">
                    <span class="product-price-old">
                      <span class="product-price-olds">1000</span>
                      <span class="product-rub">р</span>
                    </span>
                    <span class="product-price">
                      <span class="product-price">800</span>
                      <span class="product-rub">р</span>
                    </span>
                  </div>
                  <button class="product-button" type="button">в магазин</button>
                </div>
                </div>
            </div>
              <div class="img-products">
               <img class="picture-product" src="image/shop-item-desk2.jpg" alt="вкус сыра">
                <div class="products-body">
               <div class="product-body">
                  <div class="product-content">
                    <h3 class="product-title">кукла "слоник"</h3>
                    <p class="product-text">Интерьерная  кукла "Слоник", созданию которой посвящена <a class="text" href="#">весенняя серия постов</a> в блоге и несколько подкастов.</p>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="product-footer">
                  <div class="product-prices">
                    <span class="product-price-old">
                      <span class="product-price-olds"></span>
                      <span class="product-rub"></span>
                    </span>
                    <span class="product-price">
                      <span class="product-price">3500</span>
                      <span class="product-rub">р</span>
                    </span>
                  </div>
                  <button class="product-button" type="button">в магазин</button>
                </div>
                 </div> 
              </div>
              <div class="img-products"> 
                <img class="picture-product" src="image/shop-item-desk3.jpg" alt="поход в горы">
                <div class="products-body">
                <div class="product-body">
                  <div class="product-content">
                    <h3 class="product-title">шестиугольная рамка</h3>
                    <p class="product-text">Необычная рамка для украшения дома из видео <a class="text" href="#">"Как сделать рамку из подручных средств за 30 минут"</a>.</p>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="product-footer">
                  <div class="product-prices">
                    <span class="product-price-old">
                      <span class="product-price-olds">500</span>
                      <span class="product-rub">р</span>
                    </span>
                    <span class="product-price">
                      <span class="product-price">400</span>
                      <span class="product-rub">р</span>
                    </span>
                  </div>
                  <button class="product-button" type="button">в магазин</button>
                </div>
            </div>
              
              </div> 
            </div>
        </article>
    </body>

    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Высота flex-элемента `img-products` вполне совпадает с высотой родительского flex-контейнера `img-product`.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
А высоту блока `products-body` внутри `img-products` определяет его содержимое (синий фон) и отступы (зелёный фон).
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Чтобы растянуть блок `products-body` на всю доступную высоту, предлагаю его родителю, элементу `img-products` тоже задать свойство `display: flex`, но уже с `flex-direction: column`, так как два элемента - изображение и информационный блок должны располагаться друг под другом, а самому элементу `products-body`, чтобы растянуть его на всю доступную высоту, задать свойство `flex-grow: 1` ([справка](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/flex-grow))

Теперь блок `products-body` будет растягиваться на всю доступную высоту родительского контейнера (за вычетом высоты изображения выше).
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

P.S. Для красоты стоит ещё добавить элементам `products-body` свойства `display: flex; flex-direction: column;`, а блоки `product-footer` прижать вниз с помощью свойства `margin-top: auto;`

```css
*{
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    .product{
      max-width: 1200px;
      padding-left: 15px;
      padding-right: 15px;
      margin-left: auto;
      margin-right: auto;
      margin-bottom: 55px;
    }

    .title-product{
      font-size: 20px;
      font-weight: bold;
      line-height: 24px;
      text-transform: uppercase;
      text-align: center;
    }


    .title-product::after{
       content: " ";
      display: block;
      width: 64px;
      margin-top: 8px;
      margin-bottom: 23px;
      margin-left: auto;
      margin-right: auto;
      border: 2px solid #e1d9bd;
      background-color: #e1d9bd;
    }

    .img-product{
      display: flex;
      align-items: stretch;
      justify-content: space-between;
      
      }
     
     .img-products {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
      }

    .picture-product{
      width: 300px;
      padding: 25px 25px 0 25px;
      }

    .products-body{
      width: 300px;
      border: 2px solid #b59f5b;
      padding: 55px 25px 25px 25px;
      flex-grow: 1;
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
    }

    .product-title{
      font-size: 19px;
      line-height: 24px;
      margin-bottom: 15px;
      text-transform: uppercase;
    }

    .product-body{
      margin-bottom: 25px;
    }

    .product-text{
     font-size: 14px;
      font-weight: 400;
      line-height: 22px;
      color: #0f0d0e; 
    }

    .text{
      color: #b59f5b;
      text-decoration: none;
    }

    .product-footer{
      display: flex;
      justify-content: space-between;
      align-items: flex-end;
      margin-top: auto;
    }

    .product-prices{
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
    }
    .product-price-olds{
      text-decoration: line-through;
      font-size: 11px;
      font-weight: 600;
    }

    .product-rub{
      font-size: 14px;
      font-weight: 600; 
    }

    .product-price{
      font-size: 17px;
      font-weight: 600;
    }

    .product-button{
      width: 137px;
      height: 46px;
      border: none;
      background-color: #b59f5b;
      text-transform: uppercase;
      text-decoration: none;
      color: white;
      font-size: 14px;
      text-align: center;
    }
```

```html
<html>

    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
      <title>replit</title>
      <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    </head>

    <body>
      <article class="product">
          <h2 class="title-product">наши изделия</h2>
            <div class="img-product">
              <div class="img-products">
              <img class="picture-product" src="" alt="сад на подоконнике">
                <div class="products-body">
                <div class="product-body">
                  <div class="product-content">
                    <h3 class="product-title">подушки на диван</h3>
                    <p class="product-text">Набор из двух подушек с модными принтами. видео о создании <a class="text" href="#">здесь</a>.</p>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="product-footer">
                  <div class="product-prices">
                    <span class="product-price-old">
                      <span class="product-price-olds">1000</span>
                      <span class="product-rub">р</span>
                    </span>
                    <span class="product-price">
                      <span class="product-price">800</span>
                      <span class="product-rub">р</span>
                    </span>
                  </div>
                  <button class="product-button" type="button">в магазин</button>
                </div>
                </div>
            </div>
              <div class="img-products">
               <img class="picture-product" src="" alt="вкус сыра">
                <div class="products-body">
               <div class="product-body">
                  <div class="product-content">
                    <h3 class="product-title">кукла "слоник"</h3>
                    <p class="product-text">Интерьерная  кукла "Слоник", созданию которой посвящена <a class="text" href="#">весенняя серия постов</a> в блоге и несколько подкастов.</p>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="product-footer">
                  <div class="product-prices">
                    <span class="product-price-old">
                      <span class="product-price-olds"></span>
                      <span class="product-rub"></span>
                    </span>
                    <span class="product-price">
                      <span class="product-price">3500</span>
                      <span class="product-rub">р</span>
                    </span>
                  </div>
                  <button class="product-button" type="button">в магазин</button>
                </div>
                 </div> 
              </div>
              <div class="img-products"> 
                <img class="picture-product" src="" alt="поход в горы">
                <div class="products-body">
                <div class="product-body">
                  <div class="product-content">
                    <h3 class="product-title">шестиугольная рамка</h3>
                    <p class="product-text">Необычная рамка для украшения дома из видео <a class="text" href="#">"Как сделать рамку из подручных средств за 30 минут"</a>.</p>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="product-footer">
                  <div class="product-prices">
                    <span class="product-price-old">
                      <span class="product-price-olds">500</span>
                      <span class="product-rub">р</span>
                    </span>
                    <span class="product-price">
                      <span class="product-price">400</span>
                      <span class="product-rub">р</span>
                    </span>
                  </div>
                  <button class="product-button" type="button">в магазин</button>
                </div>
            </div>
              
              </div> 
            </div>
        </article>
    </body>

    </html>
```

Comment: спасибо. круто.